# how to remove the outer color of react-icons

Tags: css, react-icons

I want the close button to remove the outer color and I'm stuck on removing the outer color so somebody please help me get rid of it
below is the code

```
<IoMdCloseCircle type="button" onClick={onClose} className={styles.button} />

.button {
      position: absolute;
      top: -12px;
      right: -12px;
      font-size: 28px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #d9d9d9;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

[current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rvc3.png)

Comment: Just add `border: none`